# android Edit Text Customization

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
for (int i = 0; i < sub.length; i++) {
    tr[i] = new TableRow(this);
    EditText et = new EditText(this);
    et.setText(message2);
    tr[i].addView(et);
    EditText et1 = new EditText(this);
    et1.setText(sub[i]);
    tr[i].addView(et1);
    EditText et2 = new EditText(this);
    et2.setText(cde[i]);
    tr[i].addView(et2);
    EditText et3 = new EditText(this);
    et3.setText(crd[i]);
    tr[i].addView(et3);
    ll.addView(tr[i]);
}
```

This is my code to create four edit text components in a row.
I need to give same text parameters to all the edittext components.  But using methods to all four edittext components individually makes the code too lengthy.

Is there any solution so that I can use only one method to set text parameters for all the edittext components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a method while adding your `EditText`s to your `TableRow` can make your code easier to read.

```
private void addEditTextToTableRow(TableRow tableRow, String text) {
    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setText(text);
    tableRow.addView(editText);
}
```

Your for loop then becomes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sub.length; i++) {
    TableRow tr[i] = new TableRow(this);            
    addEditTextToTableRow(tr[i], message2);
    addEditTextToTableRow(tr[i], sub[i]);
    addEditTextToTableRow(tr[i], cde[i]);
    addEditTextToTableRow(tr[i], crd[i]);

    ll.addView(tr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try creating your components in the XML file, which will serve as a vision, and activity or in the XML Set The only text you need to set ... if you need utilzar one table, use the listView in XML and put all your EditText inside the listView